# Reuse Hibernate session in thread

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I've read somewhere that when a session is flushed or a transaction is committed, the session itself is closed by Hibernate. So, how can i reuse an Hibernate Session, in the same thread, that has been previously closed?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I've read somewhere that when a session is flushed or a transaction is committed, the session itself is closed by Hibernate.

A `flush` does **not** close the session. However, starting from Hibernate 3.1, a `commit` will close the session *if you configured `current_session_context_class` to "`thread`" or "`jta`", or if you are using a `TransactionManagerLookup` (mandatory JTA) and `getCurrentSession()`*.

The following code illustrates this (with `current_session_context_class` set to `thead` here):

```
Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Product p = new Product();
session.persist(p);
session.flush();
System.out.println(session.isOpen()); // prints true

p.setName("foo");
session.merge(p);
tx.commit();
System.out.println(session.isOpen()); // prints false
```

See [this threa](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=948638&start=0)d and the section [2.5. Contextual sessions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session) in the documentation for background on this.

> So, how can i reuse an Hibernate Session, in the same thread, that has been previously closed?

Either use the built-in "`managed`" strategy (set the `current_session_context_class` property to `managed`) or use a custom `CurrentSessionContext` *derived from `ThreadLocalSessionContext` and override `ThreadLocalSessionContet.isAutoCloseEnabled()`*.

Again, see the above links and also [What about the extended Session pattern for long Conversations?](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView#What_about_the_extended_Session_pattern_for_long_Conversations)

Comment: will rollback also close the session if current_session_context_class to "thread" or "jta"?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong. The session is stays open, just a new transaction begins. The main thing is that all objects currently attached to the session STAY attached, so if you don't clear the session you have a memory leak here.